# Oracle left join returning no rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a (now thoroughly derived) CTE:

```
feature_id | function_id | group_id | subgroup_id | type_id
1            1             null       1             null
1            1             null       null          14
2            1             null       5             null
2            1             null       null          21
3            1             null       7             null
3            1             null       null          5
```

I am trying to collate the rows together using this:

```
select C1.feature_id, C1.function_Id, C2.Group_ID, C3.Subgroup_ID, C4.Type_id
from CTE C1
left join CTE C2
    on C1.feature_id = C2.feature_id
    and c1.function_id = c2.function_id
    and c2.group_id is not null
left join CTE C3
    on C1.feature_id = C3.feature_id
    and c1.function_id = c3.function_id
    and c3.subgroup_id is not null
left join CTE C4
    on C1.feature_id = C4.feature_id
    and c1.function_id = c4.function_id
    and c4.type_id is not null
```

This gives me 0 rows...

To validate, I ran:

```
select *
from CTE C1
```

> 236 rows selected

Can anyone help? Surely the rows from C1 should be coming back...

EDIT: Fixed it with the Oracle syntax:

```
select C1.feature_id, C1.function_Id, C2.Group_ID, C3.Subgroup_ID, C4.Type_id
from CTE C1, CTE C2, CTE C3, CTE C4
where C1.feature_id = C2.feature_id(+)
and c1.function_id = c2.function_id(+)
and C2.group_id(+) is not null
...
```

(I hate the oracle syntax)

Comment: This should only return 0 rows if `CTE` has no rows.  Are you sure you have no `where` clause?

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's what I thought, but nope

Comment: `and c2.group_id is not null` all group_ids are null?

Comment: This may be a known bug:  https://community.oracle.com/thread/3548388.  I have a vague recollection that under some circumstances, Oracle may treat `on` conditions as `where` conditions incorrectly.

Comment: @artm In this case, yes. But surely it should still return the rows from C1 ?

Comment: In your code there are some wrong fields (sub_group_id and funtion_Id); is it possibile that your CTE has more columns that you expect, and this makes your query fail?

Comment: @JohnHC just for testing, can you use 4 copies of the same CTE with the same query and join on different CTEs?

Comment: With the apparent typos corrected your query does return data from the sample CTE. You may have hidden the actual problem with your simplified example code and data. It's also possible that if you have layers of CTEs you're seeing a bug in how they are being interpreted, but if so this code won't show that.

Comment: @Aleksej Typos. I don't like using the real names.

Comment: @artm It normally runs ok across multiple iterations of the same CTE.

Comment: Sometimes, Oracle bugs in CTE can be avoided by materializing the CTE.  Try changing your CTE from `WITH cte AS ( SELECT ...` to `WITH cte AS (SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */ ...)`

Comment: I've checked your first example by Oracle 11g, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it... Fixed it with the Oracle syntax:

```
select C1.feature_id, C1.function_Id, C2.Group_ID, C3.Subgroup_ID, C4.Type_id
from CTE C1, CTE C2, CTE C3, CTE C4
where C1.feature_id = C2.feature_id(+)
and c1.function_id = c2.function_id(+)
and C2.group_id(+) is not null
...
```

(I hate the oracle syntax)

Comment: I suspect that you can fix it with explicit `JOIN` syntax by putting the constant conditions in a subquery.  However, I haven't encountered this bug, so I haven't had occasion to find a fix.